# Dual boot ubuntu windows ssd in caddy

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I have a spare smaller SSD.

Can I install windows into a second SSD in caddy in my laptop dvd slot WHILE keeping my Ubuntu 18.04 OS in my main first SSD drive?

ie I am running Ububtu 18.04. I want install windows into another drive using the DVD caddy space.

-what are the exact steps I need to do to make it happen?
-Will grub detect ok or will windows boot ruin my original Ubuntu grub?
-is there an easy way to do this?

(note :-  I tried installing windows first then Ubuntu as dual boot after on one drive but so many problems with either linux or Ubuntu not booting. I tried with manjaro and I had much more problems than with Ubuntu.. so I am sticking with Ubuntu as main OS on SSD1

My Ubuntu is working great so I don't want to wipe everything and install Windows then dual boot ubuntu on same drive again.. too many problems before. Even bootrepair didn't help. I just heard that installing windows on second drive might be better? )

appreciate any advice

Answer (score 1):

In this case even though I can't give you a certain anwser, you may try this:

Since a classical way of dual-boot is "Ubuntu alongside Windows" but not "Windows alongside Ubuntu", I **strongly suggest** physically unmounting your Ubuntu HD/SSD first before you install windows on the caddy ssd. Why? Since your motherboard normally will automatically assign your Ubuntu disk as primary disk (say `/dev/sda`), so despite you want to install Windows on caddy SSD (say `/dev/sdb`), **it may overwrite boot partition on your `/dev/sda`**, which leads to your ubuntu unbootable. So, by physically removing your `/dev/sda`, since you only have one ssd on your caddy on your motherboard, windows installer can now assign its own boot partition and install everything it needs over `/dev/sdb`. Once your done, remount your ubuntu disk, boot into your ubuntu and in terminal type `sudo update-grub`  , if it detects windows boot file, then I think you're good to have dual-boot.

Comment: Kuai tks... when you mean psychically remove u mean remove Ubuntu ssd from laptop am i correct? .. but if there is no ssd in the main drive and only one ssd in the dvd caddy, won't windows live usb install the Win10into the ssd caddy and identify it as sda drive instead of sdb? since there is no sda there as it has been removed?

Comment: Yes, physically remove, in this case your concern doesn't matter because windows doesn't recognize drives as /dev as Linux does. So basically what I mean your windows is completely in caddy, while ubuntu completely in main drive. This doesn't interfere your grub to identify UEFI of Windows.