# Unable to boot Ubuntu after dual booting with Windows 10 on separate disks

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10, bootloader, hp-pavilion

I have an HP Pavilion 15 cx-0144tx laptop. It is having 128 GB SSD and 1 TB HDD, having windows10 preinstalled (obviously on 128GB SSD), I wanted to dual boot it with Ubuntu 18.04, by partitioning using windows disk management. I made 300GB Unallocated from 1TB HDD. As I wanted to install ubuntu on 1TB HDD by giving 300GB to ubuntu. 
Then I booted my laptop from live USB of Ubuntu and chose "something else"(when it asks about installation type). 
And then I chose "free space" of 300GB* and made the following partitions:

1. First partition :
   Size: 30 GB
   Type: Logical
   Location for the new partition: Beginning of the space
   Use as: Ext4 Journaling File system
   Mount Point:/
2. Second partition :
   Size : 11 GB
   Type: Logical
   Location for the new partition: Beginning of the space
   Use as: swap area
3. Third partition :
   Size: Remaining all (around 260 GB)
   Type: Logical
   Location for the new partition: Beginning of the space
   Use as: Ext4 Journaling File system
   Mount Point : /home

Then, there was an option named "Device for boot loader installation", I got stuck there. The default option selected was my 128GB SSD, I didn't change it and then installed the Ubuntu. Now after installation, when I restarted the laptop, very strange lines in CLI appeared and laptop hanged. In short, I can't boot ubuntu now. But I can use windows.

So, why didn't ubuntu loaded successfully? I think I have made mistake in choosing the boot loader location, as it is located in SSD but all other system files are in HDD.

Now, what should I do if I to delete the boot loader from 128GB SSD and wanted to have it in a separate partition in 1TB HDD? 
Is it a better option to delete all the files related to ubuntu from windows disk management and to remove ubuntu bootloader from SSD and then again do the whole process by locating bootloader in HDD this time? Yes, then how to remove all the files related to ubuntu? Now, if I show the partitions in my windows disk manager it shows the partitions properly, but an EFI file is shown extra in HDD, how to remove it(as other partitions can be deleted but not this one)?

By making a partition for the bootloader in HDD, will my problem be solved?

Last doubt, I allocated around 310GB (not exactly 300) for Ubuntu using windows disk management initially. But when I saw the free space in the Ubuntu partition menu it was around 325GB, why does it show increased?

Thanks in advance. [Screenshot of my present disk partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7XN8.png)

Comment: With gpt you do not have logical partitions. They all are same or in effect all primary. Swap file is now used by default, if no swap partition. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes I do like to have ESP on HDD and use that, but Ubiquity installer always uses first drive, sda, or NVMe. You either have to work around mounted partitions or manually re-install grub in UEFI mode. HP also is not dual boot friendly. Is Ubuntu in UEFI boot menu? Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report, do not run auto fix, yet. 
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8Xj8wwF4fQ/

Comment: Are you able to boot Ubuntu from UEFI boot menu? And from within UEFI change boot order to have ubuntu entry first in boot order? Some with HP say efibootmgr does not work with HP but using UEFI settings does.  I do like to have an ESP on every drive, but Ubiquity only uses ESP on first drive. I sometime just use sdb's ESP as backup or force an install to use it as ESP for boot.HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15 -cx0049nr Disable Optane memory
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134503/cant-boot-ubuntu-because-windows-10-rewrites-entire-efi-partition-solved

Comment: @oldfred, I have checked Intel RST app, I don't have Intel optane memory feature installed. And I can boot Ubuntu from UEFI boot menu, "Ubuntu" also appears on the screen but it's got stuck there and do not start ubuntu then. I have checked my SSD EFI partition, there is a directory of ubuntu along with windows boot manager, so I think all the EFI files of ubuntu is intact there.

Comment: I'd also like to mention (but I don't think it matters) that when you commented on my question, I've already deleted all the ubuntu partitions & also deleted EFI dir of ubuntu using diskpart & after reading comment I installed it again. This time I chose bootloader installation on 1TB HHD, but when I checked the directories using diskpart I found that it is installed in SSD again(as @oldfred said in 1st comment).  The boot info summary is of this latest installation. & plz answer me: Should the ubuntu boot properly if bootloader & root,swap,home are in different disks? What may be the problem?

Comment: Many have posted with various parts of install on different drives. Some with HP have said UEFI update allowed them to set ubuntu entry as first, but only using HP's UEFI. Others said it only was the professional level HPs that did that. The work around for HP dual booting has been to boot the fallback or drive entry that is /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. Do you have an entry that says your drive? Most had bootx64.efi as a Windows file, but now grub overwrites that with a copy of grub or shim to boot Ubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win

Comment: Probably you have the Nvidia issue of needing the "nomodeset" on the grub "linuux" line until you have the proprietary drivers installed. Do add yourself to the bug 1396379 "Does this affect me?" list.