# Deleted all partitions from my HDD, trying to install ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, hard-drive

I have deleted all my partitions, freed all the space using the Ubuntu installer that is booted up from a USB flash drive that had Ubuntu burned into it using Rufus. So after deleting all the partitions the electricity went off. Never happened in years until this exact moment.

I turned on my laptop, an HP notebook 14-r2009nx, and booted from the USB. But now I can't find the HDD. I look for it in the device for boot installation drop-down menu and nothing. I can only find the USB drive.

I looked for answers, and people are saying change SATA mode from the BIOS. I looked in my BIOS settings and I didn't find anything with the word SATA. I couldn't find where to change my HDD from IDE to AHCI.

Comment: You should see hard drive in UEFI/BIOS settings. It may say RAID or Intel RST and that is what needs to be AHCI. HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15 -cx0049nr Disable Optane memory
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134503/cant-boot-ubuntu-because-windows-10-rewrites-entire-efi-partition-solved HP Envy 17 - 18.04.1 works See post #3
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392797 You should also update UEFI from HP whether installer Ubuntu or not. And if SSD update its firmware.

Comment: I don't see the hard drive in the system configuration => uefi boot order, i can see it in the legacy boot order section

Comment: Its not the boot order, but the UEFI settings & one of the tabs. With HP probably escape f10. https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03801890