# Dual boot in HP laptop

Tags: dual-boot

Ubuntu is not supported in my laptop HP Laptop 14s-cr1xxx  so what can I do to use Ubuntu on my laptop  ? Do I need to change the generation of my laptop ?

Comment: What do you mean 'not supported'?  Ubuntu might have some problems on it, but if you let us know what they are we can help fix them.

Comment: Issues are often common across multiple models. Whether AMD or Intel makes biggest difference and if newest generation of chip also may need newest Ubuntu. Have you updated UEFI and if SSD, SSD firmware? That is needed even if not installing Ubuntu. HP Envy 17 - 18.04.1 works See post #3
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392797 HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15 -cx0049nr Disable Optane memory
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134503/cant-boot-ubuntu-because-windows-10-rewrites-entire-efi-partition-solved

Answer (score 1):

1.Boot the pendrive with rufus.
2.turn off secure boot in BIOS mode.
Now try to install again.

Thanks.