# Why Ubuntu is lagging on my laptop whereas Windows 10 works smooth?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, sound, 20.04

No matter what version of Ubuntu I use it always lags, apps open very slowly, a fresh boot doesn't even feel like a boot and fans are always running at full speed plus there's one more issue of bad sound quality. In windows there is no such issue! I own a HP Pavilion 13-an0046tu with specifications: 8th Gen intel i5, 8GB ram, 256GB SSD and integrated graphics

Comment: Think others would have you check for BIOS updates and SSD firmware updates first.  Ubuntu should run as good or better.  Will need someone who knows more about HP and Ubuntu to help better, than I can.

Comment: Older question but may be similar? Disable Optane. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134503/cant-boot-ubuntu-because-windows-10-rewrites-entire-efi-partition-solved

Comment: Hey @crip659 In past I've used the HP automatic update client and my BIOS is up-to-date but there's no firmware update available for my SSD.