# Is Ubuntu compatible with Intel 6th generation

Tags: intel-graphics, intel, compatibility

HP Pavilion 15-au062nr - PN# W2L51UA - Intel® Core™ i5-6200U - Intel® HD Graphics 520. I've tried and tried to get Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS and 21.10 (directly from Ubuntu making the .iso using their recommended software)  to install on the computer above with no luck. It freezes  right after the screen that  you enter your name, server name, login info, at or screen is blank when it gets to the installing system screen.

Comment: @guiverc I disagree about the dupe - the OP explicitly tried installing Ubuntu, and ran into an issue, so "Try it out" isn't helpful. OP: you could try installing Debian and see if that works. It is pretty simaler to Ubuntu Server. That said, guiverc is correct - we need more information to help

Comment: You gave no specifics as to what Ubuntu product, what Ubuntu release you tried to use. You also didn't detail if you validated the ISO & write to your installation media using the means appropriate for your *unstated* product & release, thus whether or not you ruled out user-error type issues.

Comment: The answer to the question that was asked is unequivocally "Yes", but answering this question won't help solve whatever problem you're having. It would be better if you would ask about the actual problem and provide details about the problem.  Otherwise this is an XY Problem. We don't have enough details about your actual problem to attempt to answer. I suggest that you close this question and compose a new question providing details about your actual problem.

Comment: Do you have Optane? Have seen multiple posts where various HP 15 models have to disable Optane. One of many: HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15 -cx0049nr Disable Optane memory
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134503/cant-boot-ubuntu-because-windows-10-rewrites-entire-efi-partition-solved